# The "user responses feed" link cover the pager

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When I look at [my responses page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3598/kiamlaluno?tab=responses), the pager is covered by the "user responses feed" link.
I notice this in Firefox 4, and Safari 5.1.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.